# UVA 750: 8 Queens Chess

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, chess, backtracking, c++03

> In chess it is possible to place eight queens on the board so that no
>   one queen can be taken by any other. Write a program that will
>   determine all such possible arrangements for eight queens given the
>   initial position of one of the queens.
>
> #### Input
>
> The first line of the input contains the number of datasets, and it's followed by a blank line. Each dataset contains a
>   pair of positive integers separated by a single space that describes
>   the initial position of one of the 8 queens
>
> #### Output
>
> Output for each dataset will consist of a one-line-per-solution
>   representation.
>
> Each solution will be sequentially numbered 1...N. Each solution will
>   consist of 8 numbers. Each of the 8 numbers will be the ROW coordinate
>   for that solution. The column coordinate will be indicated by the
>   order in which the 8 numbers are printed. That is, the  rst number
>   represents the ROW in which the queen is positioned in column 1; the
>   second number represents the ROW in which the queen is positioned in
>   column 2, and so on
>
> #### Sample Input
>
> ```
> 1
>
> 1 1
> ```
>
> #### Sample Output
>
> ```
> SOLN       COLUMN  
>  #     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  
>
>  1     1 5 8 6 3 7 2 4  
>  2     1 6 8 3 7 4 2 5  
>  3     1 7 4 6 8 2 5 3  
>  4     1 7 5 8 2 4 6 3
> ```

The full description of the problem can be found [here](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=24&problem=691&mosmsg=Submission%20received%20with%20ID%2018545721).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

class Chess
{
    const int row_size, col_size;
    const int row_queen, col_queen;
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > sol;
    // queens_row_num[i] == on which row the queen is placed on col i
    int queens_row_num[8 + 1], idx_queens_row_num;

    bool queen_is_in_attack_pos(const int &row, const int &col)
    {
        for ( int j = 1; j <= col_size; ++j )
        {
            if ( queens_row_num[j] )
        {
            if ( std::abs(queens_row_num[j] - row) ==
             std::abs(j - col) ||
             queens_row_num[j] == row || j == col )
            return true;
        }
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool eight_queens_are_in_place()
    {
        for ( int j = 1; j <= col_size; ++j )
        {
        if ( !queens_row_num[j] )
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    void store_cur_sol()
    {
        std::vector<int> v;
        for ( int j = 1; j <= col_size; ++j )
        {
        v.push_back(queens_row_num[j]);
        }
        sol.push_back(v);
    }

    void go_through_board(int col)
    {

        if ( eight_queens_are_in_place() )
        {
        store_cur_sol();
            return;
        }
        for ( int j = col + 1; j <= col_size; ++j )
        {
        if ( queens_row_num[j] )
            continue;
        for ( int i = 1; i <= row_size; ++i )
        {
            if ( !queen_is_in_attack_pos(i, j) )
            {
            queens_row_num[j] = i;
            go_through_board(j);
            queens_row_num[j] = 0;
            }
        }
        }
    }
public:
    Chess(const int &r, const int &c) : row_queen(r), col_queen(c),
                                        row_size(8), col_size(8)
    {}

    void find_solutions()
    {
        // go through the column so as to get the solution
        // in sorted order

        std::fill(queens_row_num, queens_row_num + col_size + 1, 0);
        queens_row_num[col_queen] = row_queen;
        go_through_board(0);
    }

    void print_solutions()
    {
        std::cout << "SOLN       COLUMN" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " #      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8" << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        for ( int i = 1; i <= (int)sol.size(); ++i )
        {
        std::cout << (i < 10 ? " " : "") << i << "     ";
            for ( int k = 0; k < col_size; ++k )
        {
            std::cout << " " << sol[i - 1][k];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    int T;

    std::cin >> T;
    for ( int t = 1; t <= T; ++t )
    {
        int r, c;
        std::cin >> r >> c;
        Chess chess = Chess(r, c);

        chess.find_solutions();
        chess.print_solutions();
        if ( t < T )
            std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What are the possible way to improve:

- on quality-wise
- to make it more readable so that someone can understand 6 months down the road
- to make it more C++-like

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides [what Hosch250 said](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/150818/16369), with all of which I agree, here are a few more C++ style points:

---

```
#include <cmath>
```

You don't use anything from `<cmath>`, but you do use `std::abs`, which is located in `<cstdlib>`.

---

```
const int row_size, col_size;
const int row_queen, col_queen;
```

It is generally considered bad style to declare multiple entities on the same line. Consider:

```
int const *a, b;   // what is the type of "b"?
```

Also, I see you're declaring these non-static data members as `const`. This is mostly harmless in C++03, but I strongly advise you to break the habit now.

- A class with `const` data members of primitive type will not have a default constructor implicitly defined, which means its default constructor cannot be [trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30152687/what-is-a-trivial-function).
- A class with `const` data members generally cannot appear on the LHS of an assignment; that is, you can't meaningfully assign-into it if part of its value is immutable. This hurts the pursuit of value semantics in general.
- A class with `const` data members *can* appear on the RHS of an assignment, or be returned from a function, but its implicitly generated move constructor will have to *copy* the `const` members instead of *moving* them, since they're not allowed to be modified.

Notice that the first bullet point applies only to `const` data members of primitive type, and the third bullet point applies only to `const` data members of complicated types. The second bullet point always applies, though.

Bottom line: Prefer to let your *user* determine the constness of his own variables, e.g. `const Chess c(1,1);` means that *all* the members of `c` are const, and `Chess nc(1,1);` means that *none* of them are. And the assignment `nc = c;` should Just Work.

---

```
bool queen_is_in_attack_pos(const int &row, const int &col)
```

Passing ints by const reference is weird. Anything register-sized or smaller, but *especially* primitive types like `int`, should be passed by value. The only reason to add the extra indirection of pass-by-reference is if it might be cheaper than making a copy of the value.

Also, almost all of these member functions should be qualified with `const`:

```
bool queen_is_in_attack_pos(int row, int col) const
```

since they don't mutate the `Chess` object in question.

---

```
void store_cur_sol()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    for ( int j = 1; j <= col_size; ++j )
    {
    v.push_back(queens_row_num[j]);
    }
    sol.push_back(v);
}
```

I know you said C++03 not C++11-or-later, but just note in passing that in C++11-or-later you'd be writing `sol.push_back(std::move(v))` instead of making a copy of `v` here. In C++03, to get the same level of performance, you might do something like

```
    sol.push_back(std::vector<int>());
    std::vector<int>& v = sol.back();
    v.resize(col_size);
    for ( int j = 1; j <= col_size; ++j )
    {
        v[j-1] = queens_row_num[j];
    }
```

(that is, construct the vector in the right place to begin with, instead of constructing it elsewhere and moving it into place).

---

```
Chess(const int &r, const int &c) // ...

void find_solutions() // ...

void print_solutions() // ...
```

Remind me why these are three separate member functions? If the only possible thing you can do with a `Chess` is to ask it for its list of solutions, then I don't see why the `find_solutions` method exists. It smells of [two-phase initialization](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2008/08/19/two-phase-initialization/): first the user constructs the object, and then the user goes, "Oh shoot, I also need to do *X* before this object is safe to use!"

A better design would completely initialize the object in its constructor.

Furthermore, the `print_solutions` method is either inappropriate or incompletely parameterized. To see why: Suppose I gave you the exact same problem statement, but this time I wanted the solutions printed to `std::cerr`.

Better interfaces would include

```
void print_solutions(std::ostream& out) const;  // still bad

void for_each_solution(const boost::function<void(Solution)>& f) const;  // overkill

std::vector<Solution> get_solutions() const;  // probably best
```

---

So now we have a `Chess` class that's only safe to use like this:

```
Chess c(1,1);
std::vector<Solution> sols = c.get_solutions();
```

This *continues* to smell like two-phase initialization! So we refactor again and find out that we never needed the class in the first place.

```
std::vector<Solution> sols = get_solutions_for_chess_problem(1,1);
```

I encourage you to try rewriting the program in a completely procedural style (no OO) and see which way you like better.

---

Oh, and actually I disagree with *one* thing Hosch250 said. Go ahead and use `std::endl`. In toy code like this, the efficiency hit doesn't matter because your program is done in milliseconds anyway. In real code, the efficiency hit doesn't matter because your program isn't spending any of its running time on I/O. In fact, I doubt you'll see `std::cout` popping up in *any* real-world C++ codebases. But in simple programs like this, go ahead and use `std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;` and don't listen to the people who say it should be `std::cout << "hello world" << '\n';` for speed. ;)  (And this is coming from a guy who'd write `puts("hello world");` in his own code.)

Comment: Now you're getting my confused.  I started on C++ and learned to use `std::endl`.  Now I use C#, and I get comments on my C++ answers telling me I should have told them to not use `std::endl` as well.  Now you are saying it is OK...  Good answer, and +1.

Comment: Well, the whole mess started sometime pre-1993 all because *someone* thought it would be [a great idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753060/who-architected-designed-cs-iostreams-and-would-it-still-be-considered-wel) to replace `printf("hi\n")` with `std::cout << "hi" << std::endl`. Neither one is remotely easy to explain to beginners, but at least the C-style I/O routines are somewhat *efficient*. For real work I would use C-style (POSIX) I/O; and for teaching I would follow [Kate Gregory's advice to teach almost everything else before I/O](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk).

Comment: yeah you are write, `std::abs()` is in `<cstdlib>`, but why it didn't throw any error when I compiled it ?

Comment: [c++98](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/abs/): looks like there is a `std::abs` function in `<cmath>` as well.

Answer (score 6):

First, your indentation is a little crazy, which makes it very difficult to see which code is in which scope.  Consider:

> ```
>    if ( queens_row_num[j] )
> {
>     if ( std::abs(queens_row_num[j] - row) ==
>      std::abs(j - col) ||
>      queens_row_num[j] == row || j == col )
>     return true;
> }
> ```

compared to:

```
if (queens_row_num[j])
{
    if (std::abs(queens_row_num[j] - row) == std::abs(j - col) ||
        queens_row_num[j] == row ||
        j == col)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

- I made each scope get its own indentation level.
- I gave each scope its own braces, which helps prevent bugs--especially important when working with improperly indented code.
- I put each part of the condition in the second `if` on its own line, with the boolean `||` operator at the end of the line.  I always structure my `if`s like this when the lines get too long.  I split at the `|`, `||`, `&`, `&&`, and `^` operators, but not the `==` operator or arithmetic/concatenation operators.
- This is purely stylistic, but I removed the spaces from the inside of the braces.  You are pretty consistent about this, but have a few deviations.  Consistency is more important here than the specific style you choose.

Notice how my version is easier to see what code is in what scope and executes when because you don't have to figure out what closing parenthesis and brace goes with which opening parenthesis and brace.

---

Overall, your naming is pretty good.  `print_solutions` is an excellent name, but `T`, `t`, `r`, and `c` in `main` aren't so good.  I assume the `r` and `c` stand for `row` and `column`?  Why not name them that directly?

---

No `using namespace std`?  Congratulations for not falling into that trap.

---

Using `std::endl` will flush the IO buffer, which ensures every character is printed before it lets you continue, and is a very expensive operation.  You should just use `\n` (or `System.Environment.NewLine` if you are using Visual C++), and only flush the buffer at the end of the method, if necessary.

---

I have mixed feelings about this ctor:

> ```
> Chess(const int &r, const int &c) : row_queen(r), col_queen(c),
>                                     row_size(8), col_size(8)
> {}
> ```

I like that you are setting the row size and column size in the ctor, which has a flavor of Dependency Injection and an extensible design; you can change those values to `10` and `10`, and solve the more generic N-Queens problem very simply.  The problem is that you hard-code the values in without giving the caller a chance to say which version they want solved; you should make these parameters for the caller to specify.  Because the 8-Queens problem is the most common variant of the N-Queens, these parameters could be optional, which would let the caller solve the 8-Queens problem by creating:

```
Chess chess = Chess(setRow, setColumn);
```

and the N-Queens problem by calling:

```
Chess chess = Chess(setRow, setColumn, rows, columns);
```

Comment: yeah, I should have made my code to solve N-queen problem instead of 8-queen problem, but what about `queens_row_num`. I can not declare `int queens_row_num[N + 1]` inside class. I have to declare a pointer to integers or there is any other better way to do it in case some one doesn't want dynamic memory allocation. btw thanks for pointing out other things to improve my code and about the indentation thing, it always mess up my indentation when I paste my code in the text area but anyway thanks.

Comment: When you paste your code, go back and select it, then press CTRL (or Command, for Mac) + K to format it as code.

Answer (score 4):

#### Extraneous loop = massive waste of time

This loop in `go_through_board()`:

```
    for ( int j = col + 1; j <= col_size; ++j )
```

is not necessary and in fact wastes a lot of time.  You only have to work on `col + 1`, not every column.  Once `j` becomes `col + 2`, all further computation at that point is wasted because you have skipped column `col + 1` (you didn't place a queen there).  Therefore, once you get to the last column and check `eight_queens_in_place()`, it will always return `false` because there is a queen missing from column `col+1`.

This loop also affects every level of recursion.  The topmost call spends 7x as much time as required.  The next level spends 6x.  The next level spends 5x, etc.  You probably didn't even notice the slowdown because the program finishes in a split second even with the wasted time.  That is because the 8x8 problem doesn't require much computation to begin with.  I modified your program to solve for a 13x13 board to illustrate the difference.  The results:

```
Original program (13x13 board): 54 seconds
Fixed    program (13x13 board): 0.15 seconds
```

#### Fixed version

Here is the code for the fixed version of `go_through_board()`.  Also notice that there is no longer a `eight_queens_in_place()` function because it is no longer needed.

```
void go_through_board(int col)
{
    // Advance to the next unsolved column.
    col++;
    if (queens_row_num[col]) {
        col++;
    }

    // If we reached the last column, we have found a solution.
    if (col > col_size) {
        store_cur_sol();
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise, try placing a queen somewhere in this column and recurse.
    for (int i = 1; i <= row_size; ++i) {
        if (!queen_is_in_attack_pos(i, col)) {
            queens_row_num[col] = i;
            go_through_board(col);
            queens_row_num[col] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out efficiency of the program and your comments are also very informative. I'll keep in mind next time